# tensor1d requires value to be a flat/ typedarray

Tags: python, angularjs, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I am trying a basic classification where I want to predict whether a person is having diabetics or not using 8 inputs.
I have trained the model using keras

```
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, kernel_initializer='uniform', 
activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', 
activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, 
test_size=0.3, random_state =25)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=100, verbose=1, 
validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
scores = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
model.save('logreg.h5')
```

Now using tensforjs_convertor i have converted the **logreg.h5 to model.json**

This is my **app.component.ts** where I want to use the trained model and predict

```
async loadModel() {
this.model = await tf.loadModel('/assets/model.json');
}  
async submit(form: NgForm){
this.loading= true;
var x = tf.tensor1d([[form.value.p], [form.value.glu], 
[form.value.bp], [form.value.sk], [form.value.insulin], 
[form.value.bmi], [form.value.op], [form.value.a], 
[form.value.pred],]);  
var y = tf.tensor2d([form.value.pred])
const output = this.model.predict(tf.tensor1d([x])) as any;
```

I am fetching the form values from the html 
 After running the project, The console in browser shows the following error, **tensor1d requires value to be a flat/ typedarray**

I am new to this keras and tensorflowjs, can some one help

Comment: Why do you feed tf.tensor1d() with an array of arrays? Shouldn't it just take [form.value.p, form.value.glu, ...]?

I may be completely misunderstanding your code, cause I usually do this in python, but that bit looks odd to me. It looks like you're giving the 1d tensor a 2d data chunk.

Comment: I am trying to combine AngularJs for front end , use keras pre trained model and integrate in my front end, so if the user gives input he can get the output by invoking the keras pre trained model. I have tried by form.value.p and it gives me the following error: Error when checking model : the Array of Tensors that you are passing to your model is not the size the the model expected. Expected to see 1 Tensor(s), but instead got 9 Tensors(s). @alkanen

Comment: Could you show the entire line for "var x = " when you get that error please?

Comment: You also create var x as a tensor1d, and then when you send it to predict, you put that tensor1d inside an array that you input into a new tensor1d.  Why not just run this.model.predict(x) ?

Answer (score 0):

As @alkanen already commented the value you pass to tensor1d is an array of arrays.
(`[[val],[val]]`).

As I understood the values `form.value.X` are already floats so you can simply make a float array out of them like `[form.value.p, form.value.glu, ...]` and then pass this to `tf.tensor1d()`.

And the second thing is, that `predict` and `fit` take tensors or arrays of tensors([Reference](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#tf.Model.predict)) as parameters to allow for batching, so you would just call it like `this.model.predict([x])`.

Answer (score 0):

> requires value to be a flat/ typedarray

indicates that there is an issue with the dimension or rank of the array passed in as parameter to the tensor.

[tf.tensor1d](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#tensor1d) requires the parameter to be a flat array (array of depth 1), meaning that the array should not be nested `[1, 2, 3]`.

Likewise [tf.tensor2d](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#tensor2d) requires the parameter to be an array of depth 2, it should be like `[[1, 2], [3,4]]`.

To fix the issue:

```
x = tf.tensor1d([form.value.p, form.value.glu, form.value.bp, form.value.sk, form.value.insulin,form.value.bmi, form.value.op, form.value.a, form.value.pred])
```

You declared your `y` to be a tensor2d and `form.value.pred` is used both as feature (`x`) and a label (`y`). Whether it is a typo or the architecture you're implementing. But to be coherent, the data structure is not the same in `x` and `y`. So you might consider declaring your `y` to be also a tensor1d or you make sure that you flatten `form.value.pred` before using it in `x`